# How do you close the DOM Properties window in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I am using [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) and when I had the *Inspector* open, which is accessed by right-clicking an item and selecting *Inspect Element*, I then right clicked something in the Inspector and selected *Show DOM Properties*, which you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

However I cannot figure out for the life of me how to close the **DOM Properties** window.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The feature you're referring to is called the "[split console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#The_split_console)."  You have it toggled on currently.  It will show when a tab other than the console is selected.  You can click in the split console, or command+alt+k on OSX, and hit escape to close it, or click on the console tab, or click the button in the top right of the dev tools to toggle it back off.  I find it most usefull with the debugger tab.  When the debugger is paused, you can access variables within the scope of the breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helped. +1

Answer (score 6):

Pressing escape with the DOM properties panel focused should get rid of it.